# BCP Command Line and CSV Format File Output

Tags: command-line, export-to-csv, bcp

This is my bcp command line:

```
bcp "exec DB.dbo.StoredProcedure" queryout (path to output file) -f (path to format file) -T -S<host>
```

This is my bcp format file to output a CSV file.

```
10.0
20
1       SQLINT          0       10      "\t"        1       Id      ""
2       SQLNVARCHAR 0       255 "\t"        2       Name            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3       SQLNVARCHAR 0       255 "\t"        3       Corporation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
4       SQLNVARCHAR 0       255 "\t"        4       Address1    SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
5       SQLNVARCHAR 0       255 "\t"        5   Address2    SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
6       SQLNVARCHAR 0       255 "\t"        6   City        SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
7       SQLNVARCHAR 0       255 "\t"        7   State       SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
8       SQLNVARCHAR 0       255 "\t"        8   ZipCode     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
9       SQLNVARCHAR 0       255 "\t"        9   County      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
10      SQLNVARCHAR 0       255 "\t"        10  Phone       SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
11      SQLNVARCHAR 0       255 "\t"        11  Latitude    SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
12      SQLNVARCHAR 0       255 "\t"        12  Longitude   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
13      SQLNVARCHAR 0       255 "\t"        13  Area        SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
14      SQLNVARCHAR 0       255 "\t"        14  Region      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
15      SQLNVARCHAR 0       255 "\t"        15  Email       SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
16      SQLNVARCHAR 0       255 "\t"        16  LevelOfCare SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
17      SQLNVARCHAR 0       255 "\t"        17  Description SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
18      SQLNVARCHAR 0       255 "\t"        18  Options     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
19      SQLNVARCHAR 0       255 "\t"        19  Rates       SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
20      SQLNVARCHAR 0       255 "\r\n"      20  Photos      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

The output is not getting delimited and it's all over the place. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I can't use comma as a delimiter due the content being output.

Comment: do you want csv, or tab delimited? Your fmt file shows tabs. ALSO, are you doing this in the unix/linix enviroment? If yes, then you'll want to change "\r\n" on the last record to just "\n". Finally, note the low number of users from all of your tags. Best to add something that indicate what OS and what kind of cmd-line environment (shell) you are using, i.e. widows-cmd, OR bash/ksh/csh/... Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the SO tips. I'm switching to using c# to handle the export.

Comment: coding using libraries? you think that will be easier? (as I sign all my comments  ;-) ....... ) Good luck.

Comment: i know, i know, but it's giving me better control over the data being exported and cleaning up with RegEx, anyway.